# Basic question about algebraic topology definitions

Tags: solution-verification, algebraic-topology

Trying to learn some basics of algebraic topology and wanted to ask clarifications about this sentence of Hatcher ( third page, just the beginning ;) ): 'It is true in general that two spaces X and Y are homotopy equivalent if and only if there exists a third space Z containing both X and Y as deformation retracts'. He says that the implication <= is trivial. I have a question the trivial implication and then would like to check if my solution/understanding is correct.

**Question:** Would this statement be more precise? If there exists a third space Z containing X' and Y' as deformation retracts such that X' is homeomorphic to X and Y' is homeomorphic to Y, than X and Y are homotopy equivalent.

**Trial:** First some definitions:

- $\phi_X : X \rightarrow X'$ and $\phi_Y : Y \rightarrow Y'$ are the given homeomorphism
- $r_X(t): Z \times I \rightarrow Z$ and $r_Y(t): Z \times I \rightarrow Z$ are the deformation retracts.

We need to define maps $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow X$ such that $fg$ and $gf$ are hotomopycally equivalent to the identity. One way to define a map $X \rightarrow Y$ is to embed $X$ in $Z$, than retract to $Y$. This idea formally is written:

$$f=\phi_Y^{-1} r_Y(1)i_{X'}\phi_X$$

,where $i_{X'} : X' \rightarrow Z$ is the subset embedding map, and analogously:

$$g=\phi_X^{-1} r_X(1)i_{Y'}\phi_Y$$

Now we need to define an homotopy of $gf$ to the identity. For this purpose we can try to first use $r_Y(t)$ in $f$ instead of $r_Y(1)$ (so slowly rectractin onto $Y$) and than use directly $r_X(1)$ :

$$\rho (t) : X \times I \rightarrow X, \rho (t)=\phi_X^{-1} r_X(1) r_Y(t)i_{X'}\phi_X$$

We would than have that $\rho (0)=Id$ (because $r_Y(0)$ is everywhere the identity and $r_X(1)$ is the identity restricted to $X$) ,$\rho (1)=gf$ (by direct comparison for example), and $\rho (t)$ should be continuous as a combination of continuous functions.

The definition of an homotopy between $fg$ and the identity is similar.

Is this correct? Am I overcomplicating things?

Comment: You're meant to understand it as a consequence of these two general facts: 1) homotopy equivalence of spaces is transitive; 2) if $X\subseteq Y$ is a deformation retract, then $Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $X$. You can go through the minutiae of proving those all over again, but it's unclear why one would do that.

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot, probably that is the reason why the <= is considered a trivial implication. One reason would be for me just to get acquainted with the basic definitions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct statement is in fact

> If there exists a third space $Z$ containing $X'$ and $Y'$ as deformation retracts such that $X'$ is homeomorphic to $X$ and $Y'$ is homeomorphic to $Y$, then $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy equivalent.

If $X$ and $Y$ are not disjoint, we can in general not expect to find such $Z$ containing $X, Y$ as *genuine subspaces*.

The "trivial implication" is really trivial. It suffices to observe that each deformation retract of a space $Z$ is homotopy equivalent to $Z$ (see Hatcher p.3). Since "being homotopy equivalent" is a transitive relation and "homeomorphic" implies "homotopy equivalent", we are done.

Comment: Perfect yes indeed I missed this reasoning (but it is good, I am not yet acquainted with the basic properties...). Thanks for adding all logical steps.